# Disable directory browsing wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, wamp64

Trying to disable directory browsing in wamp so my files won't be listed in localhost.

but I can't find any recent information about it and all the old video's/tutorials don't work.

I already tried to change +Indexes into -Indexes and also tried deleting it completely but it doesn't work

```
PHPIniDir "${APACHE_DIR}/bin"
LoadModule php7_module "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/php7.0.33/php7apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule unixd_module>

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin wampserver@wampserver.invalid

ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

HostnameLookups Off

DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">

    Options +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/apache_error.log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

</IfModule>

EnableSendfile off

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "${INSTALL_DIR}/alias/*"
```

I am expecting to get a forbidden page but am getting the normal localhost page

Comment: in the httpd.conf file within the <directory> tags @04FS

Comment: Change `Options +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews` to `Options +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews -Indexes`

Answer (score 1):

Left-click "Wampmanager -> Apache -> `httpd-vhost.conf`"; look there for `+Indexes` and change it to `-Indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is delete the +indexes in the file httpd-vhosts.conf